# Flask-Dance for OAuth

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am relatively new to programming, and have been learning about OAuth2 with Python. Specifically, I have been learning how to use Flask-Dance, beginning with its implementation for Google authentication. I am wondering:

1) Which Google API does Flask-Dance make use of? I see that the default scope in F-D is 'profile', but I can't seem to figure out what other scopes are available

2) What is the difference between the Google API Explorer and the Google OAuth2 Playground? When/why would I use one over the other?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.) Flask dance makes use of OAuth. Oauth is used specifically for allowing users to give authorization to your app or for authenticating users with the OpenID standard. What this means is, say, you want to get data from a user's google account, e.g. you want a list of their google contacts, you'll use OAuth to get authorization from that user. Another use case is if you want to let users login to your application using google. You'd use Oauth for that. In this case you'll be dealing mostly with access tokens and authorization codes, this is what Flask Dance is for.
For more information on OAuth, here's a video that explains it and its various use cases in plain English: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VWkQMr7r_c

2.) The Google API is for a completely different use case. You're not trying to get data from a user's google account and you're not trying to let users login to your application with google. You want to simply use a Google service on your application. For instance you want to use Google Maps in your app so that you can let users of your app get directions to a place. In this case, you'll be working with API keys that identify your application.